# Will this function cause dead-lock in multi-thread conditions?

Tags: java, multithreading

Will this function cause dead-lock in multi-thread conditions?  What's the problem of this code?

This code tries to connect a website through a given proxy in order to decide if this proxy is usable(the response code should be 200 if usable).

But this function will **never** return in some time.

```
public static boolean verifyProxy(String ip, int port ){
  boolean useful;
  try {
    URL url = new URL(VERIFY_URL);
    InetSocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress(ip, port);
    Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, addr);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(proxy);
    connection.setConnectTimeout(4 * 1000);
    int rCode = connection.getResponseCode();
    connection.disconnect();
    useful =  rCode == 200;
  } catch (IOException e1){
    logger.warn(String.format("verify proxy %s:%d exception: "+e1.getMessage(),ip, port));
            useful = false;
  }
  logger.info(String.format("verify proxy %s:%d useful: "+useful, ip, port));
  return useful;
}
```

Comment: I don't think so...still you can ask this question on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: We have no idea what the problem with this code is, because you have not told us anything about it.

Comment: @JoeC exactly...@邓辉超 you need to provide more details about the code or errors (if any)

Comment: Doesn't look like it. There is no obviously-shared resource here, so at least one of the [4 necessary and sufficient conditions for deadlock](http://nob.cs.ucdavis.edu/classes/ecs150-1999-02/dl-cond.html) may not hold.

Comment: This code tries to connect a website through a given proxy in order to decide if this proxy is usable(the response code should be 200 if usable). But this function will never return in some time.

Comment: I added some updates to my answer, maybe they help.

Comment: I have solved this problem by setting the readTimeout property by through setReadTimeout() .

Answer (score 1):

Dead-locks occur when more than one thread tries to enter a *[mutex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion)*.

Meaning: a section of code that is somehow guarded. Either implicitly, because the `synchronized` is used; or by explicitly acquiring a lock from some lock object.

The code you are showing here does **nothing** like that.

No locking translates to: no dead-locking either.

Given the latest comment by the OP: as said; you can't have a dead-lock. So when this code hangs, the obvious reason: a network problem. Yes, networking can result in all kinds of strange problems.

And reading the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html), I am wondering if there is a way for you to call `connect()` after setting that timeout.